# Out of range message and auto-reconnect - BLE Device - IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, reconnect

I am currently working on an app that gets data from a BLE device – similar to a heart monitor. The app reads the data from the device and then when it gets a specific amount of data, it creates a .csv file and uploads it into a server. Everything works fine, except when the device gets out of the range. The app just stop receiving data and doesn’t recognize that the connection is lost. I don’t get any error message. The app just stops in the middle of the “getting data” loop and keeps waiting for a data that never comes. When the device is back in the range, nothing happens.

I would like to show an alert informing that the BLE device is out of the range. When the device is in the range again, the app should reconnect to it automatically and then continue reading data from the device. How can I implement that? I tried to get the CM state – using the function below – but it didn’t work.

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central 
{
printf("Status of CoreBluetooth central manager changed %d (%s)\r\n",central.state,[self centralManagerStateToString:central.state]);
}
```

I’ve even tried to add an if clause inside the loop to check the device state, but it didn’t work also.

I am using the Texas instruments chip CC2540.

Comment: Have you implemented the `didDisconnectPeriphal` delegate method?

Comment: Agreed with @Paulw11 here. Implementing a disconnection event handler will be a 'step 1'. I've done something similar do you, and the other way you can handle it is continually track RSSI and see if it diminishes over time (e.g. theoretically, the device is getting further away). Re-connection, that might need to be done from the peripheral side - unless you want your app to continually scan and track nearby BLE devices.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. Perfect !

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Paulw11 and SJoshi (Thank you guys), I had to implement the didDisconnectPeripheral method. So, here is how I did it:

.h file:

```
// will be invoked once disconnected

-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
  didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral 
                         error:(NSError *)error;
```

.m file:

```
    -(void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central 
       didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error {

        [central connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];

        // you can add whatever you want here. 
        // will execute when the peripheral loose its connection.
    }
```